# Entry only needs num and plus validate below 8length[:8] not working

Tags: validation, tkinter, numbers

below Code is needs only num and below 8length is possible to only input number
two have purpose codes are confusion each other, therefore that is to have been made one module.

```py
def validate(*args):
    if not flowNum.get().isnumeric():
        corrected = ''.join(filter(str.isnumeric, flowNum.get()))
        flowNum.set(corrected)
    #------------------------------------------------------------
        value = limitNum.get()
        if len(value) > 2:
            limitNum.set(value[:8])

flowNum = tk.StringVar()
flowNum.trace('w', validate)
limitNum = StringVar()
limitNum.trace('w', limitnameFunc)

numinput = Entry(startframe, bd=0, textvariable=flowNum, width=6, font=(
    'verdana', 18))
```

Comment: please change your question formatting! By doing [edit] if need help, you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) article.

Comment: Is the `value = limitNum.get()` and the `if len(value) > 2: limitNum.set(value[:8])` in a new function named `limitnameFunc`? Also in the code you have posted you aren't using `limitNum` in a `tkinter.Entry`.

Comment: thank you, now I use flowNum parameter cause it returns realtime input text to show immediately thus,i want to use two parameter...